# Override labels in REST Export view

Tags: views, 8

I have a REST EXPORT view getting fields values of a node. I want to override the labels of these fields in the response returned. 
For example:- the returned response like this

```
[ 
    { 
        "question_title": "How are you?", 
}
]
```

I want the response like this

```
[ 
    { 
        "questionTitle": "How are you?", 
}
]
```

I tried to create label from the view but it doesn't affect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your view's row style options you can rename any exposed field's label. The form labels those fields as **alias**.

This is screenshot from another view I was working on, but should give you an idea.

[image: screenshot of views row style options]